# TikZ: Connect a rectangle with a horizontal line and mark intersection with a dot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am struggling with the problem how to connect a rectangle node and vertical line without using absolute ccordinates. The intersection of the two lines should be marked with a dot. I have  a strong feeling that there must be a more elegant way to achieve this.

Thanks
Marcel

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (-4,10) node (dpdata) [above]  {Data} -- (-4,0);

\node[  draw,
        align=center,
        left=of dpdata,
        yshift=-4cm,
        minimum width=2cm,
        minimum height=3cm,
        ] (ram) {Transient \\ Memory \\ (RAM)};

\node[  draw,
        align=center,
        above=of ram,
        minimum width=1.5cm,
        minimum height=1cm
        ] (mar) {MAR};

\node[  draw,
        align=center,
        below=of ram,
        minimum width=1.5cm,
        minimum height=1cm
        ] (mdr) {MDR};


\draw[color=blue,thick] (mar.east) -- (-4,9.25);
\fill (-4,9.25) circle [radius=2pt];

\draw[color=blue,thick] (mdr.east) -- (-4,3.25);
\fill (-4,3.25) circle [radius=2pt];

\draw[color=blue,thick] (mdr.north) -- (ram.south);
\draw[color=blue,thick] (mar.south) -- (ram.north);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as all your points and connections are on a rectangular grid, you can use this simple and elegant syntax for extracting coordinates (I give a simple example):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\path
(0,0) node[draw] (joe) {Joe}
(2,2) node[draw] (blow) {Blow};
;

\draw[blue] (joe -| blow) circle (2pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

the `-|` operator will extract the x coordinate from the first point (joe) and the y coordinate from the second (blow).

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, chains, intersections, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm and 9mm,
  start chain = going below,
   box/.style = {rectangle, draw,
                 text width=22mm, align=center, inner sep=2mm,
                 on chain}
                        ]
\node (mar) [box]  {MAR};  
\node (ram) [box]  {Transient Memory (RAM)};
\node (mdr) [box]  {MDR};
%
\coordinate[above right=of mar] (data);
\draw[thick, name path=A] (data) node[above]  {Data} -- + (0,-4);
\path[overlay,name path=B] (mar) -- ++ (3,0);  
\path[overlay,name path=C] (mdr) -- ++ (3,0);
%
\draw[color=blue,thick,fill,
      name intersections={of=A and B, by={a}}]   
      (mar) -- (a) circle (2pt);
\draw[color=blue,thick,fill,
      name intersections={of=A and C, by={b}}]
      (mdr) -- (b) circle (2pt);
\draw[color=blue,thick] (mar) -- (ram)  (ram) -- (mdr);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Simpler solution offer *Michael Palmer* answer. If you adopt it to above MWE, you can simple write:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, chains, intersections, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm and 9mm,
  start chain = going below,
   box/.style = {rectangle, draw,
                 text width=22mm, align=center, inner sep=2mm,
                 on chain}
                        ]
\node (mar) [box]  {MAR};  
\node (ram) [box]  {Transient Memory (RAM)};
\node (mdr) [box]  {MDR};
%
\coordinate[above right=of mar] (data);
\draw[thick] (data) node[above]  {Data} -- + (0,-4);% changed
\draw[color=blue,thick,fill]
      (mar) -- (mar -| data) circle (2pt)% changed
      (mdr) -- (mdr -| data) circle (2pt)% changed
      (mar) -- (ram)
      (ram) -- (mdr);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before.

[image]